# For i in range(n): i accepts input n amount of times and outputs total in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm very new to python and coding, class hasn't been too terrible but sometimes a simple concept will have my stumped. Once I learn the solution, I feel dumb, but at this point I already feel dumb. Please help me with this roadblock.

I want to create a function that takes an input (num_input) for how many times to repeat in the for loop (for i in num_input) which prompts the user for another input(which is a list of numbers) but N amount of times, and then prints a list of total outputs at the end. Every time I try to code it, it either returns the last input given, or a none statement. Any guidance would be appreciated, I have looked thoroughly and I assure you, I am clueless.

```
num_input = eval(input("How many cages?: "))
for i in num_cages:
    i = eval(input("Please input list numbers separated by commas: "))
in = list(i)
print (in)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Give a sample input and output

Comment: You've got a few errors here, besides execution `num_cages` hasn't been assigned, and `in` is a keyword so you can't assign things to it.

Comment: I think it's best to start with reading a basic Python tutorial before posting questions.

Comment: What is `N` ? is it equal to `num_input` or some other value?

Answer (score 2):

I dodnt understood for what purpose you used that for loop ?

```
num_input = int(input("How many cages? : "))
num_list=[]
for i in range(num_input): 
    val = input("Please input the numbers: ")
    num_list.append(val)
print(num_list)
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
print([input() for i in range(n)])
```

Tricky way .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using **num_input** to accept number of cages but right on the next line you have used variable **num_cages**, rectify it. 
Now, within that for loop `(for i in num_input)` you are accepting a numbers which are comma separated which you are storing it in loop variable **i**, use a different variable, then move your next lines where you are storing list in some variable and printing it. Also, **in** is a reserved word, not to be used for variables. So, after changes your code should be

```
num_input = eval(input("How many cages?: "))
for i in range(num_input):
    temp = eval(input("Please input list numbers separated by commas: "))
    print(list(temp))
```

Comment: why have you left the `eval`?

Comment: @cdarke eval interprets the input provided as code, for eg when temp=eval(input('Please input list numbers..')) is executed, user will type in 1,2,3. Now, without eval it will be stored as string, but just because you used eval around it, it is stored as a tuple

Comment: I actually meant on the first `input`, `num_input = eval(input("How many cages?: "))`.  I would replace `eval` with `int`.

Comment: Input provided in first line would be a number ofcourse, but will be stored as string, calling range(str) would throw an error

Comment: So wouldn't `int` be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, int would have been more appropriate, disadvantages of copy pasting :D

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is wrong, but as Racialz said, it is a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve.

First off, you haven't defined `num_cages`. I assume you meant to use `num_input`. Also, if you want to run a `for` loop a certain number of times, you have to use the `range()` function. Also, to hold the various lists the user inputs, you should create a blank list (I've called mine `num_list`) of which to append the inputs.

```
num_input = eval(input("How many cages?: "))
num_list = []
for i in range(num_input):
    i = eval(input("Please input list numbers separated by commas: "))
    num_list.append(i)
print(num_list)
```

This saves the inputs as tuples, but you could change them to lists if that's what you want to do.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: Also you tried to define `in` as a variable, however it is a python keyword, so you should call it something else.

Comment: thank u this really helps. I'm very new to coding (CPE 101 new), so I apologize for a weird description. But I appreciate this very much and have learned a lot from the different answers. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Just letting you know that if this question solved your problem, could you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and guide you through this.

First of all, a little clarity of purpose: what we want to do is generate a list of lists. The user enters a number (`num_input`) that determines how many times we ask him for a list of numbers. Then, we loop `num_input` times, each time asking the user to give us a list of numbers. In the end, we want to print the result.

Let's start.
First of all, what variables do we need? Something to hold the maximum number of lists (`num_input`), something to hold the lists the users inputs (`user_lists`), a temporary variable to hold the user input (`temp`) and a counter to use in the loop (`i`).

The first thing to do is get the number of loop iterations from the user: `num_input`. This is easy:

```
    num_input = int(input("How many cages? "))
```

The main difference between this code and your code is the use of `eval`. It is generally not recommended to use `eval` in a user input situation, especially since you know very well what is your expected input type (an integer). And, as another advantage to not using `eval`, if the user submits something that is not an integer (for example a character) the program will stop and give an error.

After we get the user input, let's start asking the user to input the list of numbers. Like this:

```
    user_lists = []
    for i in range(0, num_input):
        temp = input("Please input list numbers separated by commas: ")
        temp = [int(n) for n in temp.split(",")]
        user_lists.append(temp)
```

In this chunck of code we get the user input and also process that input and save it. But first of all we initialize our `user_list` as an empty list. Then, counting from 0 to `num_input` times, we start the actual process. Once we have the user input (supposedly a list of numbers) saved in temp, we start the actual tricky processing part.

This line:

```
        temp = [int(n) for n in temp.split(",")]
```

Is the one responsible with processing the user input and turning it from a string to a list. What happens here? Well, we use a python trick called "[list comprehensions](https://www.google.ro/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=python%20list%20comprehensions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=shY0V6GdNczgaZPVv7AK)". It's a nifty shortcut that lets you use a loop to define the contents of a list. And what we are doing is taking the user input, splitting it into a list of components (eliminating the commas) and then looping through these components and converting them to integers. If that's a bit hard to understand, check out the sample code below, which does the same thing as the one-line above:

```
    entry_list = user_input.split(",")
    result_list = []
    for entry in entry_list:
        result_list.append(int(character))
```

Nice shortcut right?
So, now we have our results in the `user_lists` variable and want to print them. Here you have a couple of options.

1.You could just print it out as a list of lists:

```
    print user_list
```

2.Or you could print it a bit more user-friendly, with one list per row:

```
    for entry in user_list:
        print entry
```

I hope this rather long explanation helps you understand the code better.
And as a challenge for you, try to understand this one-liner:

```
    print([map(lambda x: int(x), input("Please input list numbers separated by commas: ").split(",")) for i in range(int(input("How many cages? ")))])
```

It does the same thing as the code above.